# How to check data in sharedpreferences using ternary in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences, ternary

I want to check my data inside sharedpreferences.. whether it is exist or not using ternary.. is there a way to do that? here is the code

```
            Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                   //I want to check something inside sharedpreferences here but I don't have any idea to do that
                     (something I want to check) ? do something :
                      isLoading
                          ? Text("Loading...")
                          : (_image == null)
                              ? Text('In')
                              : (_data.length == 0)
                                  ? Text("Try again")
                                  : fail
                                      ? Text("Try again")
                                      : DateFormat("HH:mm:ss")
                                                  .format(DateTime.now()) ==
                                              "23:59:59"
                                          ? changeTime()
                                          : Text("Success")
                    ],
                  ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

> Take one boolean variable

```
bool isVisible = true;
```

> now update your `isVisible` variable inside `getLoginStatus()` method

```
void getLoginStatus() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String userData = prefs.getString('YourKEY');
    if (userData?.isEmpty ?? true) {
      setState(() {
        isVisible = false;
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        isVisible = true;
      });
    }
  }
```

> Now you can need to call `getLoginStatus()` when you need to check the value in `sharedpreferences`

```
Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[

                     isVisible ? do something :
                      isLoading
                          ? Text("Loading...")
                          : (_image == null)
                              ? Text('In')
                              : (_data.length == 0)
                                  ? Text("Try again")
                                  : fail
                                      ? Text("Try again")
                                      : DateFormat("HH:mm:ss")
                                                  .format(DateTime.now()) ==
                                              "23:59:59"
                                          ? changeTime()
                                          : Text("Success")
                    ],
                  ),
```

Comment: so what I need to do with my code is replacing sentence : ```something I want to check``` with getLoginStatus() ... am I right?

Comment: I get an error, what do you mean by ```Constants.createTripStatus``` and my data inside shared preferences is a object..like {"a":"b","c":"d"}.. and I want to check whether "c" is null or not... is there something that should I add from your code?

Comment: @uyhaW you need to pass your `SharedPreferences` key instead of `Constants.createTripStatus`

Comment: wait I will try again

Comment: there is something that make me confused... when I have to call ```getLoginStatus``` ?

Comment: you can call inside `initState()` method

Comment: I do understand now and it works well with your help.. thank you very much for your help :DDD